# The Direct Product $H\times K$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(\vert H\vert, \vert K\vert)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

This is Exercise 1.12.1 of Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*.

> Let $G\cong H\times K$ be a direct product of finite groups. Show that every element of $G$ has order dividing $\operatorname{lcm}(\vert H\vert, \vert K\vert)$.

Here $H, K$ are finite groups (of course).

### My Attempt:

Let $g=(h, k)\in G$. Then $g^{\vert G\vert}=e_G=(e_H, e_K)$. Let $\gamma=\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$. We want to show that $$\gamma\mid\operatorname{lcm}(\vert H\vert, \vert K\vert).$$

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** By definition of $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$ it suffices to show that
$$g^{\operatorname{lcm}(|H|,|K|)}=e_G.$$

Comment: Thank you. I've written my own answer based on yours. Does that work?

Comment: @Shaun Yes that's right.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mu=\operatorname{lcm}(\vert H\vert, \vert K\vert)$. Then $\mu=\vert H\vert u$ and $\mu=\vert K\vert v$ for some $u, v\in\mathbb{Z}$ by definition of $\mu$.

Also, for $g=(h, k)\in G$,
$$\begin{align}
g^\mu&=(h, k)^\mu \\
&=(h^\mu, k^\mu) \\
&=((h^{\vert H\vert})^u, (k^{\vert K\vert})^v) \\
&=(e_H^u, e_K^v) \\
&=(e_H, e_K) \\
&=e_G.
\end{align}$$

Thus $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)\mid \mu$ by definition of $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$.